# Error while starting hive which: no hbase in()

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Everything was working fine until today I tried to run HIVE and it prints the following error log.

```
    which: no hbase in (/hadoop/anaconda3/bin:/hadoop/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/opt/novell/eDirectory/bin:/opt/novell/eDirectory/sbin:/opt/novell/migration/sbin:/opt/novell/ncl/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1/sbin:/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1/bin:/hadoop/db-derby-10.10.2.0-bin/bin)
    Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/hadoop/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at oorg.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//hadoop/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).

        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:483)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)

        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:420)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:338)


    javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:515)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 81 more
------

NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//hadoop/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 81 more
------

        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:529)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:834)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:338)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:217)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:515)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)

        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//hadoop/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:420)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:338)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:217)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

        ... 81 more
------

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.generateSQLException(PoolUtil.java:192)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:422)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:483)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:420)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).

        a
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

        ... 81 more
```

Comment: Hive doesn't need Hbase, but you're using the embedded default Metastore, which is only going to cause problems

Comment: Is the port available? `Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused`

Comment: yeah, I have even checked the services running

Comment: If you just download Hbase, and put it on your PATH, what happens?